# CHAID analysis options for OS X / Python / R

Tags: python, r, macos, machine-learning

I am looking for a good open source (or low cost) way to perform CHAID analysis. My favorite language is python, but R is ok too. OS X is a must.

I've found this package for R: http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/chaid/  but can not find documentation on how to use it.

Anyone aware of good documentation of how to do CHAID analysis in an OS X environment? I'd like to avoid the SPSS / Answer Tree based solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: I recently wrote an open-source package in python for CHAID [here](https://github.com/Rambatino/CHAID)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package is documented and the code is relatively simple. Here an exmple from the help of `chaid`:

```
library("CHAID")
 
### fit tree to subsample
set.seed(290875)
USvoteS <- USvote[sample(1:nrow(USvote), 1000),]
ctrl <- chaid_control(minsplit = 200, minprob = 0.1)
chaidUS <- chaid(vote3 ~ ., data = USvoteS, control = ctrl)
print(chaidUS)
```

[image]

**PS** *Many married and well educated people who like BUSH And young single woman like GORE:)*

Comment: Neat! I'm relatively new to R and didn't think to look inside R for the documentation. I was expecting to find documentation somewhere on the web.  Thanks for your answer.. This may be enough to get me started.

Comment: Hey @agstudy - just curious: are you available for a couple hours of paid tutoring? I'd appreciate some professional guidance on learning to adopt this technique in a variety of data sets.  If interested my email is in profile. Hit me up with a rate.

Comment: How did you generate the graphic?

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in:

party (ctree):
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf

partykit (used to generate the CHAID package on r-forge):
http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2009/slides/Hothorn+Zeileis.pdf
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/index.html